# HERE Geocoder Autocomplete API missing results compared to Geocoder API

Tags: autocomplete, here-api, autosuggest

I am trying to implement an input box for building names in Hong Kong that autosuggest as the user is typing.

Naturally **Geocoder Autocomplete API** would seem to be the obvious choice. But having done some testing, I found that the results returned from **Geocoder API** to be more accurate and comprehensive. **Geocoder API** also returns more results and to a better granularity.

For instance, building names that correctly resolve to **Match level** - **houseNumber** on **Geocoder API**, are resolving to **street** level on **Geocoder Autocomplete API**. Plus a lot more relevant results are returned for **Geocoder API**.

So my thoughts are to use **Geocoder API** over **Geocoder Autocomplete API**, but this appears to render the **Autocomplete API** a bit redundant.

Can anyone advise whether there are any advantages to using **Geocoder Autocomplete API** over **Geocoder API**? 
At the moment, I can't see any point in using the **Autocomplete API** given it's lower level of accuracy and missing results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HERE Geocoder Autocomplete API does a best match based on your input parameters and also limits the number of returned suggestions to a maximum of 20. If you think you need more results and that the HERE Geocoder API itself returns more relevant results for your use case then there is no problem using it.

Comment: In that case, I shall go with the Geocoder API. As in some cases the Geocoder Autocomplete API returns no results at all, when the Geocoder API returns several. Big thank you for the quick response!

Comment: if you need more info on a selected address from Autocomplete, then query the Geocoder using the "locationId", e.g.

.../geocode.json?locationid=NT_CxIpArCJ9zIMcx2D8AQUkA&...